# Update an entity (many to many relationship ) with Entity framework using devExpress listBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listbox, devexpress

I have Many to Many relationship between two entities (Roles and Rights).
In role edit form I have two listBoxes, the first one contains all available rights and the second one contains the rights that the role has. And I can move items between the two lists.

When I click on the edit button I want to update the role with all the rights that are located in the second listBox.

Roles.aspx

```
    <table style="width: 100%">
             <tr>
                <td style="width: 35%">
                       <div class="BottomPadding">
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblASPxListBox1" runat="server" Text="Droits disponibles:" />
                        </div>
                       <dx:ASPxListBox ID="ASPxListBox1" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientInstanceName="ASPxListBox1">
                             <Columns>
                                  <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="name" Name="name" />
                             </Columns>

                        </dx:ASPxListBox>  
                </td>

                 <td style="width: 35%">
                    <div class="BottomPadding">
                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblChosen" runat="server" Text="Droits accordés:" />
                    </div>
                    <dx:ASPxListBox ID="ASPxListBox2" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientInstanceName="ASPxListBox2">
                         <Columns>
                              <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="name" Name="name" />
                         </Columns>
                    </dx:ASPxListBox>  
                    </td>  
              </tr>       
            </table>
```

Roles.aspx.cs

```
    // Update method

    Control listBox2Control = grid.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ASPxListBox2");

    int selectedId = (int)grid.GetSelectedFieldValues(new string[] { "Id" }).FirstOrDefault();
    using(AccountModelContainer context = new AccountModelContainer())
    {

    Role role = (from r in context.RoleSet
                 where r.Id == selectedId
                 select r).FirstOrDefault<Role>();
    ASPxListBox listBox = (ASPxListBox)listBox2Control;

    List<Right> rights = (List<Right>) (listBox.DataSource);

    role.Right = rights;

    context.RoleSet.Attach(role);//Error
    context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When I click on the edit button I get the following error:

> "Impossible to define the relationship between two objects, because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."

What should I do to prevent this exception?